# Can you change organisation ownership of a Google Cloud Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to change the Organisation Ownership of a Google Cloud Account from one organisation to another?

Initially we setup the account under `domain.net.au`.

Our company was purchased by another company and has setup emails using google under `domain.ag`.

My boss is now wanting the Google Cloud Account and all its projects to be moved over to `domain.ag`.

Is this possible without having to re-create them all in the new location?
We have a massive database that is highly important to our company that needs to have almost no downtime.

thanks!

Comment: Your account is not owned by the domain name. To change the domain name, you must engage Google Cloud Support. You can also create a new organization and move the projects. My advice is to engage Google Cloud support to modify your organization. Update your question with details on what is configured, e.g. using Google Workplace, the concern/problem, etc. Projects do not care about the domain name. The org can use one domain name and services within a project can use any number of domain names. The connection between Google Workplace and your Google Cloud Organization is important.

Comment: thanks @JohnHanley I am awaiting on information from the `domain.ag` side of things as I did not set that up, nor do I have access to it.. yet

Answer (score 1):

Changing organisational ownership I think you really have to contact support. But if what you meant is moving your resources from the old organisation account to the new one,Yes it is possible to Move resources from one organisation to another. With the right Migration plans and the projectmover roles to the required accounts you can. But note that the resources would not inherit policies from previous organisations hence you have to do accurate setup for your new organisation. Just do an inventory record of what's in the current organisation to know how to prepare the new organisation to avoid issues. If you encounter any error, then you can rollback

Comment: It's the correct answer. You can elaborate with screen shot and with better focus on Organization policies not inherited (and the issues that can raise)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thank you @Osemenkhian, I will look further into this when I gain access to the new organisation

Answer (score 1):

To change the organization ownership first you need to [contact google](https://enterprise.google.com/supportcenter/managecases) support. Also yes, it is possible if you want to move your resources from an old organization account to a new organization account with correct [migration](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration) plans and roles. Kindly make a note here, the resources would not inherit policies from previous organisations. Hence you need to do the exact setup for your new organization account.

Steps to [change](https://medium.com/google-cloud/moving-gcp-projects-between-iam-organizations-12c417915bcb) Organizational ownership.

1. Create a list of projects that you’d like to move.
2. Move all the projects out of any folders in the current organization and into the top level.
3. Contact Support with a list of projects that you’d like to move from the current organization to another organization.
4. Support will move the projects out of the current organization so they have no parent (no organization).
5. Move all the projects into the new organization.

Comment: thank you @Tatikonda, I will look further into this when I gain access to the new organisation